# MySQL replication of only one database

Tags: mysql, replication

I just wanted to check on the replication setup I've got working. The plan was to replicate just one database, so per the MySQL documentation I used the [replicate-do-db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db) flag in my MySQL configuration. However per the documentation it says it won't work if your code uses "db.table" format of inserts...

> Note that this does not replicate
>   cross-database statements such as
>   UPDATE some_db.some_table SET
>   foo='bar' while having selected a
>   different database or no database.

So, does my combination of the replicate-do-db flag AND the replicate-wild-do-table flag fix this?

```
replicate-do-db = replicate_me
replicate-wild-do-table = replicate_me.%
```

I was just wondering, as the replication works as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that *all* `db.table` `INSERT`s won't work, it's that *cross-database* ones won't (see the example in the doc page you link to).  Your replication probably works because you're not doing any cross-database `INSERT`s; most people don't.

`replicate-wild-do-table` won't change anything for this purpose.

Comment: Ah! Cheers for the clarification.